# CSS Object-fit:cover get coordinate as original width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, aspect-ratio

I have image of size 750*750.
I have used the css for 2nd image-

```
object-fit:cover
```

In the below screenshot, both the images are same but are placed in different container.
Now if have click on image,i get the co-ordinate using event.offsetX and event.OffsetY.

Since i have used object-fit:cover for 2nd image,it is displaying small.
i have information of tire co-ordinate,as the 2nd image get small i want to get its co-ordinate.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

to get the actual dimension you should use

```
img {
    width: 750px;
    height: 750px;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: I need the click co-ordinate with respect to original image size